# Home networking setup

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I have a networking question to all the experts out there.

Currently I have two TP-LINK TL-WR1043. One is connected to a cable modem and acquires a dynamic IP from the ISP. It acts as a router (192.168.0.254), DHCP server (192.168.0.100-249) and an Access Point with the SSID_1 network. I want to expand the network to the other room using a wired connection and use the builtin switch on the other TL-WR1043 and broadcast the same wireless network.I use Gargoyle on both routers at the moment but can switch to DD-WRT easily.

My question is how to accomplish that?

I don't want to use a wireless bridge since I have a wired connection between both routers.

Please see the network diagram I would like to achieve:

### NETWORK DIAGRAM:

[image]

Comment: Not familar with that particular router but basically you want the 2nd "router" to function at layer 1 / layer 2 only. You should be able to turn off DHCP and the routing functions on the 2nd one so it only functions as a switch / access point. I would also make sure that the APs broadcast on different channels.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple if your **first** router is handling **DHCP** properly and acquiring WAN IP from cable network.

You should **disable DHCP function** in the **second router** and plug it directly via a proper cable (cat 5e will be enough for gigabit speeds) to your network.

DD-WRT is **not mandatory** for your usecase.

If you want proper wireless coverage and since **both your routers** use the **b/g/n 2.4GHz band**, I highly advice you to avoid overlapping by switching the **first router's channel** to 01, and **the second** to 06 or 11. (and vice-versa depending on the crowdedness in your area).

You can verify which band is used by other AP's in your area using this freeware:

[Acrylic Wi-Fi Monitoring Tool](https://www.acrylicwifi.com/en/wlan-software/wlan-scanner-acrylic-wifi-free/)

Comment: Also make sure to limit your DHCP range to ensure (however unlikely) that your second router's IP won't be handed out by the first router and cause a conflict which knocks every device it is handling offline.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. The device in the second room was in Repeater/Bridge mode and it connected to the SSID_1 wirelessly hence the low bandwidth. 
After changing it to Gateway/AP mode and disabling the DHCP server it all acted as expected. It even broadcasts the SSID_1 but on a different channel.

Thanks everybody for the suggestions.